# Can't figure out why my video/buttons isn't being uploaded to my server in react

Tags: reactjs

this is my HeroSection.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import { Button } from './Button';
import './HeroSection.css';
import video from './video-2.mp4';

function HeroSection() {
    return (
        <div className='hero-container'>
            <video src={video} autoPlay loop muted />
            <h1>SEE WHERE WILL YOU RESIDE NEXT</h1>
            <p>What are you waiting for?</p>
            <div className='hero-btns'>
                <Button className='btns' buttonStyle='btn--outline'
                buttonSize='btn--large'
                >
                 GET STARTED
                </Button>
                <Button className='btns' buttonStyle='btn--primary'
                buttonSize='btn--large'
                >
                   WATCH TRAILER <i className='far fa-play-circle' />
                </Button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default HeroSection;
```

and my code for Button.js is

```
import React from 'react'
import './Button.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const STYLES = ['btn--primary', 'btn--outline'];

const SIZES = ['btn--medium', 'btn--large'];
export const Button = ({children, type, onClick, buttonStyle, buttonSize}) => {
const checkButtonStyle = STYLES.includes(buttonStyle) ? buttonStyle: STYLES[0];
const checkButtonSize = STYLES.includes(buttonSize) ? buttonSize : SIZES[0];

return (
    <Link to='sign-up' className='btn-mobile'>
        <button
        className={`btn ${checkButtonStyle} ${checkButtonSize}`}
        onClick={onClick}
        type={type}
        >
            {children}
        </button>
    </Link>
  )
};
```

I think there is something wrong with my Button.js which is why none of it appears in my localhost server but I can't figure out what. Maybe it has something to do with props but I am a beginner and don't exactly understand it all too well